# How to split a data set with two distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

I have two normal distributions with equal sizes mixed together into one data set, it is assumed both have similar std, only the mean of both distributions is different. What will be easiest way to find both means in such? When I plot a histogram of the data I can clearly see both means, but I would like to script in some way so running the calculation on the data set will output both means

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Expectation_maximization_(EM) for an algorithm on estimating the parameters of a Gaussian mixture model. The details are too much to outline in a comment and I have not the time to detail a full answer. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try